# Strange JQuery Append Not Completing DIVs

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am having some trouble with Jquery append feature.  I am wanting to have a DIV around a PHP while loop, so I did this code and the opening div tag is called, but the closing div tag isn't registering with its opening tag:

```
$('.class').append('<div class=\"class_name\">');
\\ While Loop
$('.class').append('</div>');
```

Comment: Just generate your PHP and then have jQuery wrap it in a DIV. The PHP is processed first and then sent to the browser where jQuery can work on the generated result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery only appends complete elements, you can't append an opening div tag without jQuery automatically closing it. Try building an html string and then appending that string.

```
var strOutput = "<div class='class_name'>";

// replace this with php loop: for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  strOutput += i;
// replace this with php loop: }
strOutput += "</div>";
$(".class").append(strOutput);
```

**UPDATE**
assuming you did a php while loop and generated a variable called $strOutput:

```
$strOutput = "<div class='class_name'>some text here</div>";
```

add it to your javascript like this:

```
echo "$('.class').append('$strOutput');";
```

**another update**

Read between the lines! That was just an example... Build a single string, then echo it.

```
$strOutput = "<div class='class_name'>";
// within your while loop...
$strOutput = $strOutput."somevalue";
// now after your while loop...
$strOutput = $strOutput."</div>";
echo "$('.class').append('$strOutput');";
```

Comment: How does my PHP while loop fit into this?

Comment: Basically, use your php to create one long string, then append that whole long string at once as a single div. I don't do a whole lot of php, so i'm not posting a php while loop for you. If you posted your original loop, i wouldn't mind modifying it to work in my code.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you are saying.  I'm not super familiar with JS, but where does my string or long variable go inside your code?  just add `strOutput += varName`?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you put the output from the while loop in a variable and then append it to the div.

**Updated**

```
var output = //the output from the while loop
```

<strike>`$('.class').append('<div class=\"class_name\"></div>').append(output);`</strike>

```
var div = $('<div class=\"class_name\"></div>').append(output);    
$('.class').append(div);
```

Comment: This appends output to `.class`, not the generated `.class_name` div though the concept would work.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the code in your while loop to a varable and then echo it out in the jquery append call.

As Kevin B said above, jQuery appends only complete elements, so do something like this:

```
<?php
//while loop (save whatever you'd echo/output to a var
?>

$('.class').append('<div class="class_name"><?=$output_from_while_loop?></div>');
```